# Django File not uploading inlineformset createview

Tags: python, django

My UpdateView working but I am not understating why file is not uploading in my CreateView?

here is my code:

**froms.py**

```
class BlogForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:  
     model = Blog
     fields = ['title','body']

ImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Blog,BlogHeaderImage,fields=('image',),extra=1)
```

**views.py**

```
class BlogCreate(CreateView): #file is not uploading in create view? 
      model = Blog
      template_name = 'blog_post.html'
      form_class = BlogForm

      def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['latest_posts_list'] = Blog.objects.order_by('-id')
        return super(BlogCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
      
      def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data["children"] = ImageFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        else:
            data["children"] =ImageFormSet()
        return data

      def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        context = self.get_context_data()
        children = context["children"]
        self.object = form.save()
        if children.is_valid():
            children.instance = self.object
            children.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
      def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("blog")

class BlogUpdate(UpdateView): # Updateview is working and image file is uploading 
      model = Blog
      template_name = 'blog_update_post.html'
      #fields = ['author','title','body']
      form_class = BlogForm
      def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data["children"] = ImageFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES, instance=self.object)
        else:
            data["children"] =ImageFormSet(instance=self.object)
        return data
      def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        children = context["children"]
        self.object = form.save()
        if children.is_valid():
            children.instance = self.object
            children.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
      def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("blog")
```

I am also not getting any errors. After click on update button I successfully redirected in Blog page without uploading file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where I did mistake. I forgot to add  `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in my html form. After add this the problem was solved.